# Authorization Required Error?

Tags: apex, force.com

I have created a new registration page , when i am going to browse, this page is displaying following error

[image]

I have gone through all the sites for Setup --> Develop --> Site --> Public Access Setting and Login Setting Option and provided the full access but i cant find the solution.

How can i solve this error ? and tell me why its displaying this error ?

Comment: Have you allowed access to the underlying controller class as well? If not then that is an issue.

Comment: Also access to any objects and fields that the controller may make use of

Comment: i allowed all of the classes, custom objects and vf pages .but its not working ...?

Comment: There is a field, object, class, or vf page that the public site user does not have access to. Even missing one field access will cause you this problem. The only way to solve it is for you to review every requirement. Another option is to run the page as the logged in SF user by using the URL to load the page and see if there is an error as that could also be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Amit please give access to your page that you have created

please follow the steps how to give access to your page .

Go to your site --> Click on your site ---> you can see site visualforce pages -->click on edit and and select your page which you have created .

and now check whether what you selected in your site landing page .

[image]

Hope this solves your problem

Cheers

Vineeth